# Algorithm to generate (and verify) string of 4 quad alpha numeric code

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, credit-card, key-generation

I am writing a system, for which I need to generate unique transaction numbers (which can be verified by myself). I want to use something similar to that used by credit cards, where a string of the form:

```
([A-Z0-9]{4}[\s]){3}[A-Z0-9]{4}
```

I want to be able to craft an algorithm that generates only a subset of the range of keys possible from the set of all possible combinations of keys above.

I don't know much about security, but I'm guessing that the solution would probably involve coming up with a logic procedure that restricts the generated set, such that members of the 'valid' set, satisfy a CRC check.

I would be grateful if anyone could shed more light on how to implement this.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format-preserving ​ ​

Comment: This is probably doable, but it depends on what other properties you want your generated numbers to have.  The easiest implementation would simply be a 15-digit base 36 number (0-9 + A-Z), which gets increased by 1 each time, and then a Luhn check-digit appended.  Of course, that pattern would be really obvious to anyone who had several sequential transactions, but you may not care about that.  If you *don't* want the numbers to be guaranteed sequential, it can get more advanced.